# Send HTML report and Cucumber reports through Jenkins to email

Tags: html, email, jenkins, report

I m looking for sending HTML reports through jenkins to Outlook. I tried all the possible ways like installing Editable email notification and Cucumber reports but could not succeed. Could you please let me know what are the config changes which i need to make in jenkins to get HTML reports to my mail

Answer (score 0):

I tried below steps and i was able to send the report as an attachment

you will have to find the smtp server of the domain for that

1. run this command `dig +short mx xyz.com`
2. Examine the first response, and ignore the port
3. Now in Editable email notification fill in the details and path of your html report e.g. `target/html/index.html`
4. In the advanced setting check "trigger always"
5. Now check if the mail is sent after the build

I hope this works for you.